# Prove that: $\int_0^{n\pi}f(\cos^2(x))\,dx=n\int_0^{\pi}f(\cos^2(x))\,dx?$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, trigonometric-integrals

If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, how can I show that $$\int_0^{n\pi}f(\cos^2(x))\,dx=n\int_0^{\pi}f(\cos^2(x))\,dx?$$

I know how to show that both integrals exist.  I believe that $n$ is a multiple of $\frac12$.  I thought that the identity $\cos^2(x)=\frac{\cos(2x)+1}{2}$ would be useful, but maybe not.  I think I should use some change of variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that if $f$ is continuous on \[0,1\], then: $\int_0^\frac\pi 2 f(\sin x)dx=\int_0^\frac\pi 2 f(\cos x)dx= \frac12\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538801/show-that-if-f-is-continuous-on-0-1-then-int-0-frac-pi-2-f-sin-xdx-i)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

- $$\int_0^{n \pi}f(\cos^2(x)) \, dx = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \int_{i\pi}^{(i+1)\pi}f(\cos^2(x))\,dx$$
- Period of $\cos^2(x)$ is $\pi$.

Typically $n$ refers to integer, though you are right that if $n$ is a multiple of $\frac12$, the result holds too. To see that use some symmetry.

Comment: start with proving $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(\cos^2(x))\, dx = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} f(\cos^2(x))\, dx$?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{split}\int_0^{n\pi}f(\cos^2(x))dx &=& ~~\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_{i\pi}^{(i+1)\pi}f(\cos^2(x))d x \\ &\overset{t= x-i\pi}{= }&~~\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_0^\pi f(\cos^2(t))dt~~~\cos(t +i\pi) = (-1)^i\cos t \\ &=&n\int_0^\pi f(\cos^2(t)) dt
\end{split}