# Cosine function and Riemann integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> $$\int_0^{n\pi} f(\cos^2 x )\, dx = n \int_0^\pi f(\cos^2 x )\, dx$$

I am studying the chapter on Riemann integral so wondering if this equality requires the concept of Riemann integration to prove or there are other methods?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. For these expressions to be well defined you would already need Riemann integration, but I assume that's not what you're asking.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538801/show-that-if-f-is-continuous-on-0-1-then-int-0-frac-pi-2-f-sin-xdx-i

Answer (score 0):

Since $\cos^2(x+\pi)=(-\cos x)^2=\cos^2 x$ the function $g(x):=f(\cos^2 x)$ is $\pi$-periodic. It is then obvious that
$$\int_0^{n\pi}f(\cos^2 x)\>dx=\int_0^{n\pi} g(x)\>dx=n\int_0^\pi g(x)\>dx=n\int_0^\pi f(\cos^2 x)\>dx\ .$$

Comment: Why was there a need to introduce the function g? Seems unnecessary in the working